# Android Automated testing using JUnit and integrated testing Framework

Tags: android, automated-tests, android-testing

i am developing an app in android..Am not so much aware of testing methodes .And i have choosen the Junit for automated testing
Now i need to know that Weather Junit and integrated framework is best fit for the purpose or i have to use any other tool for this?
please explain

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The problem with testing an elaborate framework like Android is you must mock an entire smartphone just to run a Hello World app and test it.

So you must use JUnit, because that's the only test runner that Android's own testing libraries support. So, to get test suites like `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2`, you must start with JUnit. But major props for even writing tests! That puts you above the majority of the programmers in this industry...

If by "integrated framework" you mean FIT, however, skip it. That stuff is just for high-end consulting.